# Adding rowspan to table causes all but one row to shift to the right

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, html-table

I'm  generating a table via jQuery.

When I try to add a `rowspan` it applies only to one cell, causing cells in the other rows to shift to the right. How do I apply the `rowspan` correctly to all the affected rows?

```js
function formatHtml(data) {
  var $elem = $("<table>", { 'class': 'table table-responsive table-bordered overview-table' });
  var $thead = $('<thead>', {}).appendTo($elem);
  var $theadTR = $("<tr>", {}).appendTo($thead);
  $("<th>", { 'width': '50', 'html': 'Tijd' }).appendTo($theadTR);
  $.each(data.workernames, function(i) {
    $("<th>", { 'html': data.workernames[i] }).appendTo($theadTR);
  });
  var $tbody = $("<tbody>", { 'class': 'overview_table_td' }).appendTo($elem);
  var click = '';
  var html = '';
  if (data.shopTimeArray.length === 0) {
    $tbodyTR = $("<tr>", {}).appendTo($tbody);
    $tbodyTD = $("<td>", { 'class': 'empty', 'html': 'Geen tijden beschikbaar voor vandaag.', 'colspan': data.workernames.length + 1 }).appendTo($tbodyTR);
  }
  $.each(data.shopTimeArray, function(i) {
    $tbodyTR = $("<tr>", {}).appendTo($tbody);
    $tbodyTH = $("<th>", { 'scope': 'row', 'html': data.shopTimeArray[i].slice(0, -3) }).appendTo($tbodyTR);
    $.each(data.workerids, function(j) {
      workername = data.workernames[j];
      if (typeof(data.workerTimes[data.workerids[j]]) != "undefined" && $.inArray(data.shopTimeArray[i], data.workerTimes[data.workerids[j]]) !== -1) {
        click = 'make_app("' + data.today + '","' + data.shopTimeArray[i].slice(0, -3) + '","' + workername + '","' + data.workerids[j] + '","' + data.dayname + '","0")';
        html = '';
        classname = 'orange';
        $rowSpan = 0;
        $.each(data.workerAppointments[data.workerids[j]], function(k) {
          if (data.shopTimeArray[i] == data.workerAppointments[data.workerids[j]][k].time) {
            if (data.workerAppointments[data.workerids[j]][k].timeArray != "undefined") {
              $.each(data.workerAppointments[data.workerids[j]][k].timeArray, function(y) {
                $rowSpan++;
              });
            } else {
              $rowSpan = 0;
            }
            classname = 'orange white';
            html = data.workerAppointments[data.workerids[j]][k].clientname;
            appointmentid = data.workerAppointments[data.workerids[j]][k].appoimentid;
            strong = data.workerAppointments[data.workerids[j]][k].clientday;
            if (strong != undefined) {
              click = 'show_app("' + appointmentid + '","strong")';
            } else {
              click = 'show_app("' + appointmentid + '")';
            }
          }

        });
        $tbodyTD = $("<td>", { 'class': classname, 'onclick': click, 'html': html, 'rowspan': $rowSpan }).appendTo($tbodyTR);
      } else {
        click = 'make_app("' + data.today + '","' + data.shopTimeArray[i].slice(0, -3) + '","' + workername + '","' + data.workerids[j] + '","' + data.dayname + '","1")';
        classname = 'grey';
        html = '';
        $.each(data.workerAppointments[data.workerids[j]], function(k) {
          if (data.shopTimeArray[i] == data.workerAppointments[data.workerids[j]][k].time) {

            classname = 'grey white';
            html = data.workerAppointments[data.workerids[j]][k].clientname;
            appointmentid = data.workerAppointments[data.workerids[j]][k].appoimentid;
            strong = data.workerAppointments[data.workerids[j]][k].clientday;
            if (strong != undefined) {
              click = 'show_app("' + appointmentid + '","strong")';
            } else {
              click = 'show_app("' + appointmentid + '")';
            }
          }
        });
        $tbodyTD = $("<td>", { 'class': classname, 'onclick': click, 'html': html }).appendTo($tbodyTR);
      }
    });
  });
  return $elem;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered overview-table" width="100%" border="1"><thead><tr><th class="dark" style="width: 50px;">Tijd</th><th class="dark">Kapper 1</th><th class="dark">Kapper 2</th></tr></thead><tbody class="overview_table_td"><tr><th scope="row" class="dark">01:30</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","01:30","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","01:30","Kapper 2","196","1","1")"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" class="dark">01:45</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","01:45","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","01:45","Kapper 2","196","1","1")"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">02:00</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","02:00","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","02:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">02:15</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","02:15","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","02:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" class="dark">02:30</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","02:30","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange white" onclick="show_app("106","strong")" rowspan="0">Test treatment</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">02:45</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","02:45","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","02:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">03:00</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:00","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">03:15</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:15","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" class="dark">03:30</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:30","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange white" onclick="show_app("4614")" rowspan="2">test</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">03:45</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:45","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","03:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">04:00</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","04:00","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","04:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">04:15</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","04:15","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","04:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">04:30</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","04:30","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","04:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">04:45</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","04:45","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","04:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">05:00</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","05:00","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","05:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">05:15</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","05:15","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","05:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">05:30</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","05:30","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","05:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">05:45</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","05:45","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","05:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">06:00</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","06:00","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","06:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">06:15</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","06:15","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","06:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">06:30</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","06:30","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","06:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">06:45</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","06:45","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","06:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">07:00</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","07:00","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","07:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">07:15</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","07:15","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","07:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">07:30</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","07:30","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","07:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">07:45</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","07:45","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","07:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">08:00</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","08:00","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","08:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">08:15</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","08:15","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","08:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">08:30</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","08:30","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","08:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">08:45</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","08:45","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","08:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">09:00</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","09:00","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","09:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">09:15</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","09:15","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","09:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">09:30</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","09:30","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","09:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">09:45</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","09:45","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","09:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">10:00</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","10:00","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","10:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">10:15</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","10:15","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","10:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">10:30</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","10:30","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","10:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">10:45</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","10:45","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","10:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">11:00</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","11:00","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","11:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">11:15</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","11:15","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","11:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">11:30</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","11:30","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","11:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">11:45</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","11:45","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","11:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">12:00</th><td class="orange white" onclick="show_app("4612")" rowspan="6">test</td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","12:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">12:15</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","12:15","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","12:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">12:30</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","12:30","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","12:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">12:45</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","12:45","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","12:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">13:00</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","13:00","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","13:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">13:15</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","13:15","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","13:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">13:30</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","13:30","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","13:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">13:45</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","13:45","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","13:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">14:00</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","14:00","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","14:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">14:15</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","14:15","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","14:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">14:30</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","14:30","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","14:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">14:45</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","14:45","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","14:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">15:00</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","15:00","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","15:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">15:15</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","15:15","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","15:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">15:30</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","15:30","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","15:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">15:45</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","15:45","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","15:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">16:00</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","16:00","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","16:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">16:15</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","16:15","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","16:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">16:30</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","16:30","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","16:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">16:45</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","16:45","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","16:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">17:00</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","17:00","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","17:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">17:15</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","17:15","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","17:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">17:30</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","17:30","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","17:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">17:45</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","17:45","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","17:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">18:00</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","18:00","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","18:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">18:15</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","18:15","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","18:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">18:30</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","18:30","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","18:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">18:45</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","18:45","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","18:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">19:00</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","19:00","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","19:00","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">19:15</th><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","19:15","Kapper 1","148","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","19:15","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">19:30</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","19:30","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","19:30","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr><tr><th scope="row">19:45</th><td class="grey" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","19:45","Kapper 1","148","1","1")"></td><td class="orange" onclick="make_app("2017-06-19","19:45","Kapper 2","196","1","0")" rowspan="0"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Your title is not acceptable. please write the problem in the title and not something that ends with "X not working"

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're drawing the same number of `<td>` tags in every row, while also using `rowspan` on some cells.

When you use `rowspan`, that cell is *added* to the table rows below it -- it does not replace the cells in those rows. So those later rows end up containing four cells, one from the `rowspan` above, and the others from the literal `<td>` tags.

You need to omit those extra `<td>` cells from the table rows following the `rowspan`, either by scanning through the table after it's drawn and deleting the redundant cells, or (better) by not drawing them in the first place.

The logic in your `formatHtml()` is complex enough that I'm not going to try to untangle it, but in pseudocode the approach I'd take would be

- For each row:

  - For each column:

    - If this cell represents the beginning of an appointment, draw a `<td>` with a `rowspan` based on the appointment's duration
    - If this cell represents the middle of an appointment, draw nothing and go on to the next column
    - otherwise draw an empty `<td>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps me but i don't know how do omit them via jquery.

Comment: @NiravJoshi I updated the answer with one possible approach.

Comment: Let me do this hope this will work. Thank you again